# Can I adjust "jump to symbol" in VS Code to "jump to method/function/class"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am used to Sublime Text 3 and currently experimenting with Visual Studio Code. In Sublime, I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and "goto anything" (prefix "@"). This will only show functions, methods and classes for Python in my case.

In VS Code, I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and get "jump to symbol". It is essentially the same list plus many more things which I never need (e.g. import statements, global variables, and parameters of functions). Can I get a similar list as sublime shows, e.g. removing especially function parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with Ctrl+T ? And if this don't work you could use the [Sublime Text Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.sublime-keybindings).